# short story of post-apocalypse survivor with stainless steel dentures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

This was one story in a paperback collection of three stories, all by the same author I believe.  The collection was titled "Three Tales of the Wolf".

In the post-apocalypse story, the desert-dwelling survivor kills a courier delivering desperately-needed vaccines to a high-tech enclave.

In the second story, people start wearing prosthetic memory devices called 'Ticklers' that manage their schedule, send messages, and give them an advantage in business.  The Ticklers become sentient and begin using their humans as hosts.  The hero persuades the Ticklers that Earth is too small for their ambitions, so they build a spaceship and abandon the human race.

In the third story, pressures building up in the human race cause increasing violence and suicides.  Governments respond by inventing an alien threat and moving the economy to a war manufacturing footing.

Comment: The middle story is **"[The Creature from Cleveland Depths](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76811/story-about-big-brother-like-society-where-everybody-wears-a-controlling-wristwa)** ("*tickle*", not "*tickler*", btw). It was collected in [The Night of the Wolf](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?230757) by Fritz Leiber

Comment: That looks right. The first one would be "The Night of the Long Knives" (here *The Wolf Pair*), "My plates were stainless steel biting and chewing ridges, smooth continuous ones that didn't attempt to copy individual teeth"

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That's the one. Do you want to do the honours or shall I?

Comment: Go ahead. I'm busy at work. :)

Comment: Probably "Sanity" for the third one, although I have not found a summary yet.

Comment: Another question about "Night of the Long Knives": http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58851/post-apocalyptic-story-in-a-book-where-man-and-daughter-scavengers-jump-a-pilot

Answer (score 9):

**You're describing the novella collection "[The Night of the Wolf](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?230757)" by Fritz Leiber.**

- The first story (the one with the dentures) is [**The Night of the Long Knives**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97839), retitled [The Wolf Pair](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97839).

> *My plates were stainless steel biting and chewing ridges, smooth continuous ones that didn't attempt to copy individual teeth*

- The second story is [**The Creature from Cleveland Depths**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76811/story-about-big-brother-like-society-where-everybody-wears-a-controlling-wristwa), retitled [The Lone Wolf](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97840) - Already covered in another answer on the site. For the record, it was a 'tickle', not a 'tickler.

> *An engineer devises a little clockwork/tape-based thing where a man
> can make notes and reminders, and the device would give the wearer a
> slight shock, a "tickle" when the time hit, reminding him to check his
> appointments.*

- The third story about violence and suicides is [**Sanity**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40971), retitled [**Crazy Wolf**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40971) -

> *“Modern life” has driven everyone insane, but the World Manager has a secret ten-year plan.*"
> <sub><sup>[“Sanity,” Fritz Leiber, 1944 - Jennre Review](https://jennre.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/sanity-fritz-lieber-1944/)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's it!!! Thanks so much!  I'd upvote your answer, but I'm just a guest...

Comment: Since you are relatively new to the site, if the answer is correct, please mark it as so by clicking the gray check mark to the left.

Comment: How old are these stories?  1976, eh?  The "tickle" reminds me of my cell phone vibrating when I have an alarm go off...